# Passing partial arguments in tcshell

Tags: unix, parameters, shell, tcsh

I'm writing a shell script (tcsh) that is supposed to received 3 parameters or more. The first 3 are to be passed to a program, and the rest are supposed to be passed to another program. All in all the script should look something like:

```
./first_program $1 $2 $3
./second program [fourth or more]
```

The problem is that I don't know how to do the latter - pass all parameters that are after the third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `shift` as follows:

```
./first_program $1 $2 $3

shift # shift 3 times to remove the first 3 parameters.
shift
shift

./second program $*
```

`$*` will contain the remaining parameters.

You must also do error checking before you do a `shift` by checking `$#argv` and ensuring it is non-zero. Alternatively you can check the value of `$#argv` at the star of the script and ensure that it is atleast `3`.

Answer (score 2):

I present to you the `shift` command:

> `shift` [variable]
>   Without  arguments,  discards  `argv[1]`  and shifts the members of `argv` to the left.

Example:

```
$ cat /tmp/tcsh.sh
#!/bin/tcsh

echo "$1" "$2" "$3"
shift
shift
shift
echo "$*"
$ /tmp/tcsh.sh 1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3
4 5 6
```